# SQLiteException: near "''" in Android 2.1

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sdk-2.1

I encountered and FC on my app when testing on Android 2.1 device.
This happens in this query when I want to match PRODUCER_ID to an empty string.

```
managedQuery(CONTENT_URI, new String[]{Constants.NAME,
Constants.PRODUCER_ID}, Constants.PRODUCER_ID + " IS NULL OR " +
Constants.PRODUCER_ID + " IS ''", null, null);
```

Exception:

```
android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "''": syntax error: ,
while compiling: SELECT name, producer_id FROM beverages WHERE
producer_id IS NULL OR producer_id IS ''
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Substitute "=" or "like" for "IS".

"is null" or "is in (...)", "is between","is not null", etc etc are all valid.  "is ''" isn't.